# Scrub Brush encased in the footcuts through the heaviest stains

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "[footcut](https://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/hoover-steamscrub-2-in-1-steam-mop-blue/6000196441219)" in "Scrub Brush encased in the footcuts through the heaviest stains"? I found "[foot cut](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foot%20cut#:%7E:text=Definition%20of%20foot%20cut,seating%20on%20the%20wall%20plate)" on Merriam-Webster instead of "footcut", but I don't think they (foot cut and footcut) mean the same thing. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have read the Walmart text correctly:

> Scrub Brush encased in the **footcuts** through the heaviest stains

However, this contains a typo. The page should read like this:

> Scrub Brush encased in the **foot cuts** through the heaviest stains

Product descriptions are often terse. You might understand this one better if you read it like this:

> [There is a] Scrub Brush encased in the **foot** [that] **cuts** through the heaviest stains.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed explanations!